# Particular report about contribution on CiviReport

Tags: civireport, contributions, reports, donations

Good morning, 
I'm writing to ask if it exist a particular report about contributes.
I'd like to have a report which contain these columns: Surname/Name, amount and date of the last donation and total contribution, contribution AVG and number of donation for every donor. 
Over this, I need also the filter in order to research specific group of donator, like campaing, group, contact type, sex,... 
Does it exist?
What I have to do if I need it?
Tanks to all... and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use several reports for what you are asking. But the Contribution Summary report has most of what you are asking for.

1. Look at Contributions > Contribution Reports > Contributions Summary. This report will give you most of what you are asking for. Under Filter you can set your date range, financial type, and other criteria. Under Grouping if you Group by Name or Contact ID you will probably get the results you are wanting, but try other options. You probably want to uncheck Group by Date.  IN the columns tabs you can select what is displayed in the report, Name, state, etc. Check Contribution Amount Stats to see the total # of contributions from each donor, their Contribution $ Aggregate and Average.
2. In the previous report, you can click on a donors name to see their profile. But you may need to use the Contribution Detail Report to dial into specific donors. This would be to see their last contribution.

Comment: Tank you! But It doesn't exist a report containing already the coloumn date and amount of the last contribution?

Comment: I thought that you could use Contribution Ordinality in Filters. But you are correct, that does not do Last. It just does First and Second.

Comment: If you install the Summary Fields extension, you can add the date and amount of the last contribution to the Contribution Summary report.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look at using the [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension

Comment: Tank you, It is very useful, but I need a possibility to interrogate a report. I'm asking a specific type of report, not a tab for every contact. Anyway tank you for the help

Comment: if you are using Drupal I would think about building a view and using the Summary Fields